# Trying to play with collections using Meteor and React

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm studying Meteor and React and I'm creating a small app that allow users to create messages. Quite easy... but I can not get rid of join collections.

What I'm using is [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) to help me doing the dirty job but I'm lost...

Here is the code so far:

messages.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { publishComposite } from 'meteor/reywood:publish-composite';

export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  publishComposite('messages', {
    find() {
      return Messages.find({}, {
        sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      });
    },
    children: [
      {
        find(message) {
          return Meteor.users.find(
            { _id: message._author }
          );
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

And within my React component I created this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.messagesTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('messages');
      const messages = Messages.find({}, {
        sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      }).fetch();
      console.log(messages);
      this.setState({ messages });
    });
  }
```

In the documentation of publish-composite I see it use `Template.topTenPosts.helpers` to fetch data and I don't know how to emulate the same with React...

What the logs show is just the messages data without any user information:

```
Object
createdAt:Sat Jul 15 2017 18:17:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)
message:"A message..."
_author:"6M8wNbt4Ff2YTN99u"
_id:"2gL2xKbWnduYqTHXk"
```

How can I get rid of it? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

publish-composite doesn't do a true *join* - it returns all the relevant documents from multiple collections. You still need to show the related information on the client side. In your case you are displaying *messages* but you also need to show the *author* information. Your React component must access both collections to display documents from each.

Start with:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.messagesTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('messages');
      const messages = Messages.find({}, {
        sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      }).fetch();
      const authors = Authors.find({}).fetch;
      this.setState({ messages, authors });
    });
  }
```

Now your component can access both the messages and (related) authors in its state. If you show your render code then I can augment this answer with how to put the pieces together in your layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following this approach I don't receive a collection with "populated" information about the author but I still have to iterate through authors to get the right name of the author for each message. Actually I'm trying [perak:joins](https://atmospherejs.com/perak/joins) to see if it works good as I expect. In case I will try your approach. Thanks.

Comment: You're right - it doesn't do a traditional join, it just makes sure all the required data ends up on the client. It's then up to you to pull it together in your render.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

[perak:joins](https://atmospherejs.com/perak/joins) is the package I used to get it work properly and it is very easy to use:

messages.js:

```
[...]
export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

Messages.join(Meteor.users, '_author', 'author', ['profile']);

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('messages', function() {
    return Messages.find({}, {
      sort: { createdAt: -1 }
    });
  });
}
[...]
```

`componentDidMount` has no changes and the result of `messages` is the one expected with a new field called `author` filled by the `profile` object.